# Provided og:image URL could not be processed due to EU news domain license restriction

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I got this error when try to share my website on Facebook on any account other then the official Facebook account of my webpage. Debugger tool suggests me to look at: https://www.facebook.com/help/533727544131571 but I've already verified my domain and nothing changes.

What else could I do?

EDIT:
These are og tags in my `<head>` (but again everything works when shared on the blog's official page on Facebook, but it doesn't when shared on any other account or when previewed in Facebook debugger tool):

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="#URL#">
<meta property="og:title" content="Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Description">
<meta property="og:image" content="#IMG_URL#">
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with verified your domain. The link you linked to say you have to fill in https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/191435726167388 .

Comment: @WizKid: Interesting ... when I open the suggested link there's no link to the form you mentioned, but to the webpage about domain verification (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification/verifying-your-domain/) 

Comment: Our firm verified the domains...but nothing happened ..we are waiting a month now